# Who are currently connected to my DSL-Modem?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, modem, dsl-modem

In my home there are some devices that connected to my DSL-Modem at the same time. (such as PC - Laptop - SmartPhones etc...)

I would like to know who are currently connected to my DSL-Modem ?

I want a list as below which represents IP addresses currently are connected to DSL-Modem :

```
192.168.1.10 # PC IP address
192.168.1.25 # laptop IP address
192.168.1.15 # SmartPhone IP address
```

P.S :

If it matters :

DSL-Modem model : `D-Link DSL-2730U`

Comment: Go to your router IP (`ipconfig` to obtain IP info - for most routers - and the gateway IP is the one to log in to) -> log in -> there should be a tab or page regarding "LAN" -> You should then be able to see links or information regarding connected devices, their MAC addresses and the IP addresses they have been assigned (DHCP)

Answer (score 3):

See [page 78](http://setuprouter.com/router/dlink/dsl-2730u/manual-1648.pdf) of the user manual.

You can view the connected wireless devices in `Wireless` - `Station Info` category on the `http://192.168.1.1` page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use your router's web interface to see the list of connected devices.

If you only connect wireless devices you can view associated wireless stations in `Station Info` section of your router web interface:
[image]

If you have a mixture of wired and wireless devices and you use DHCP at the same time (which is as a regular setup at home), then you can check your DHCP lease table in `DHCP` section

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am using an android app called 'fing'. It does the exact same thing that you asked.

Comment: Good app. I use it but the "definitive" answer is to connect directly to the router as that is the device that devices are connecting to. What if Fing doesn't display a device that you know is connected and works?

Comment: Yes very true. But one has to go to the router page and look into the device which may or may not be present ( couldn't find that option in my router ). So the alternate is to use this app. The app does show all the devices. It also shows the devices that are offline but the router assigned IP to that device .

Comment: Also fing will work on any modem and any wifi network